# How to perform division by row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, division

I have a dataframe on which I would like to perform a division based on the entries. To illustrate the problem, say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame([[1.,2.,3.,4.], [5.,6.,7.,8.], [9.,10.,11.,12.]],
                  columns=['A','B','C','D'], index=['x','y','z'])
```

So I get the following as `df`:

```
   A   B   C   D
x  1   2   3   4
y  5   6   7   8
z  9  10  11  12
```

What I would like to do is see how much each value in column D changed as I went from x to y, and again to z.

The dataframe I'd get would be:

```
   A   B   C    D
x  1   2   3  NaN
y  5   6   7  2.0
z  9  10  11  1.5
```

How do I do this in a systematic way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) with the column [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed:

```
In [21]:
df['D'] = df['D'].div(df['D'].shift())
df

Out[21]:
   A   B   C    D
x  1   2   3  NaN
y  5   6   7  2.0
z  9  10  11  1.5
```

Or more succinctly:

```
In [23]:
df['D'] /= df['D'].shift()
df

Out[23]:
   A   B   C    D
x  1   2   3  NaN
y  5   6   7  2.0
z  9  10  11  1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [pct_change()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.pct_change.html):

```
In [57]: df.D.pct_change() + 1
Out[57]:
x    NaN
y    2.0
z    1.5
Name: D, dtype: float64
```

or as DF (on the fly):

```
In [58]: df.assign(D=df.D.pct_change() + 1)
Out[58]:
     A     B     C    D
x  1.0   2.0   3.0  NaN
y  5.0   6.0   7.0  2.0
z  9.0  10.0  11.0  1.5
```